# What's the name for sequences that oscillate between negative and positive values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, definition

Professor said there is a name for sequences that oscillate between negative and positive values. I said that's called "divergent" but he told me I was wrong. I am wondering what this term might be. Is it jargon or something obvious?

Comment: Do you mean an “alternating” sequence?

Comment: A sequence of the form $(-1)^n a_n$, $a_n \geq 0$, is called "alternating".

Comment: Such a sequence is not even necessarily divergent. Consider $(-1)^n/n\to0$.

Comment: Also "oscillating" sequence would be a fitting name too. That would encompass cases like $e^{ikn}$ when $k$ is not necessarily $\pi$